# Strings with \0 behave weird in Java

Tags: java, string, null-terminated

Why is a different to b?

```
    String a = "BuildGUID10035\0528\0440";
    String b = "BuildGUID10035" + '\0' + 528  + '\0' + 440;

    System.out.println("A: " + a);
    System.out.println("B: " + b);
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

Comment: For a reference on character escaping in Java, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are different because in the first string, `\052` gets interpreted as a single octal escape sequence (and so is `\044`).

The following two strings do compare equal:

```
String a = "BuildGUID10035\000528\000440";
String b = "BuildGUID10035" + '\0' + 528  + '\0' + 440;
```

(I've replaced the `\0` with `\000` in `a`.)

Answer (score 2):

\052 and \044 are octal representations of characters. Anything starting with \ and three digits are considered as octal forms of characters. Hence, two strings are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

\ followed by 3 digits represent octal escape sequence. So, string a becomes BuildGUID10035*8$0 an so not equal to string b.

Answer (score 1):

\0 is placeholder for null character. So the first string is interpreted as \052 ... \044 where as the second is BuildGUID10035{NULL}528{NULL}440

(Obviously I've used NULL as an example of what I mean...)

\052 and \044 would be interpreted in their own right